# Java, spring-data-commons, cannot create Range<LocalDate>, why?

Tags: range, spring-data-commons

Java `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`, but it should have implemented `Comparable<LocalDate>` to allow for creating a `Range<LocalDate>`. This is so because the declaration is `Range<T extends Comparable<T>>`:

[spring-data-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/Range.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/Range.java#L29)

The question is could the `spring-data-commons` `Range` have the following class declaration:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
```

This could maybe help with being able to create `Range<LocalDate>`.